# How to make an application use local shared library instead of the system one

Tags: application-development, libraries, qt-creator

I have qtcreator installed using the qt online installer. It ships which its own version of qt library. The qt library are also installed in the system directories, but those are older.
I have problems with qtcreator (see [qt-forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/53907/black-screen-areas-in-designer-qtcreator)). Suspecting this might be because Qt is using the old system libraries, I ran qt using

```
strace -e open qtcreator.sh
```

and indeed, it uses the libraries in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/

To load the correct libaries, the qrcreator.sh script sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH to

```
/home/<me>/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib:/home/<me>/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator
```

this is correct, but still, the libraries from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator are used.

How can I tell qtcreator to use the local libraries despite the existence of the system wide libraries?

Comment: Try this: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HOME}/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/:${HOME}/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` and give me a comment with @A.B.

Comment: [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/618687/edit) your question and post the line with the export of "/home/<me>/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib:/home/<me>/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator"

Comment: @A.B. That does not make a difference. And I do not see why it should, it results in the same LD_LIBRARY_PATH, does it not? The qtcreator.sh script (shipping with qtcreator) is a little bit lengthy I think. I know that the posted LD_LIBRARY_PATH is correct because I added a "echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to the script. If you still want I can post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Nathan's option, I would add `patchelf` which allows to change the `RPATH` of an executable. I personally prefer patching `RPATH` over defining `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and the like, since Ubuntu has issue defining these in `profile` and also as if not defining this in `profile`, this save the need of a wrapper script.

To define an executable `RPATH` which is relative to the application's directory (if you wish to, that's not mandatory to do so), you have to use `$ORIGIN` **taking care to escape the `$`** which must appears literally (so use `\$ORIGIN` if you invoke `patchelf` from a shell). Ex. if the application belongs a `bin` directory and the libraries belongs to a peer `lib` directory, you will use `$ORIGIN/../lib` for the `RPATH`.

You may as well use an absolute `RPATH` if you prefer.

See [Patchelf (nixos.org)](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html).

Answer (score 0):

One can preload libraries using the "LD_PRELOAD" environment variable. Simply specify the full path of the so files like this:

```
export LD_PRELOAD = "/path/to/so1.so /path/to/so2.so"
```